# Multi-word Google search returns no results

Tags: javascript, html

We just added a new Google Custom search to our site, but it doesn't process multi-word searches. If you enter one word it works fine, if you enter two or more words, it returns "No Results"

Also, when it returns the results, the search field displays the search terms like this "Word%20Word%20Word"

Here is the code Google gave us to use:

```
<!-- The following javascript appears before the closing </head> tag. -->
<script>
(function() {
var cx = '012938749785999463601:bae5a4ajf2q';
var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
'//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
</script>

<!-- This tag is inserted where the search box should render -->
 <gcse:searchbox-only></gcse:searchbox-only>
```

You can see the search function at the following URL:

http://amazingribs.com/search_results.html

Ok, I figured out the issue, but I don't know how to fix it. It may not be possible for me to fix it, if it is an internal Google issue.

What I noticed was, if you type two or more words into the search field--like "Corned Beef"--you get back "No Results", but when you examine the URL you'll notice that the search term appears as "Corned%2520Beef". The search function is inserting an extra "25" in the term, instead of simply %20. If you manually delete the "25" from the URL, the multi-word search returns results normally.

Can this be fixed within the script shown above? Or, is this a internal Google problem?

Comment: Something is double-encoding the strings. `%25` is how you encode a "%" character.

Comment: It's definitely on the Google side. Tracing with Firebug shows that the query goes out as 'q=corned%20beef'. The response has 'q=corned%2520beef' in it.

Comment: So, there's a problem on Google's server?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the solution to the bad results is taking the "www" out of our target URL for the results page in the Google Control Panel.

Sounds goofy to me, but hey, it worked.

So, if anyone else is having the same problem, check your result page "target URL" and remove "www" from it

So now, instead of: http://www.amazingribs.com/search_results.html

we use: http://amazingribs.com/search_results.html

And, then it works! Of course, this information was not on the Google help page anywhere or in the Control Panel instructions.

Thanks to anyone who looked at this question. Everything is working now.